# How to publish AWS Lex bot on a internal SharePoint site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sharepoint, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

Thanks for your time on my post. I am at beginner level on bot development and working on a chatbot PoC, I created a AWS Lex bot with intents that initiates AWS Lambda functions to fetch data from S3 and deliver data back to the user using Lex.  This part is just working fine. As next steps,  I would like to publish this bot on an internal SharePoint site? I tried using AWS Cloud formation and provided SharePoint site info but for me it is not working. I believe I need to establish connectivity between AWS Lex and SharePoint and might be missing key steps . Please advise. Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a way to dock your Lex chat bot in your Sharepoint site. To do that, you would need to deploy a chat widget to Sharepoint that will allow your Sharepoint users to interact with your Lex bot.
Have a look at this sample Web UI : https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui